# unmanaged Network Manager in ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu

After installing Ubuntu again, I noticed a problem, and the problem is that the Applet Device Manager displays an empty Wi-Fi tag. If I'm connecting to the Internet (by LAN), and when I click the right method, most options are inactive and below the Ethernet Network Device not managed! (Attached Pictures)
I now imported my openvpn connection but I can not connect to it.

I also made these changes:

```
/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf
```

First it was

```
[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile

[ifupdown]
managed=false

[device]
wifi.scan-rand-mac-address=no
```

And I changed ifdown to this

```
[ifupdown]
managed = true
```

but problem not solve

Similarly, I can not connect to the VPN network, and I feel that these two problems are quite interrelated!

Comment: Welcome to StackExchange! Have you noticed that there is an Ubuntu-specific StackExchange site, called [AskUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com)? In there is [this question](https://askubuntu.com/q/2901/769591), which seems very similar to your situation.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/q/71159/452474

Answer (score 12):

use this it worked out for me i am using ubuntu desktop 18.04

```
touch /etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/10-globally-managed-devices.conf
sudo service network-manager restart
```

Comment: Yep. That worked for me also in 19.10. But I don't really know why. Can someone explain what's going on there?

Comment: This works for me on 19.04 too. Don't know why neither.

Comment: hi there @GonzaloAguilarDelgado,@Lee, I am now using ubuntu 20.04.by default I found out 10-globally-managed-devices.conf do not exist in **/etc/.../** by using touch you create a file that is similar to the one available at **/usr/lib/NetworkManager/conf.d/10-globally-managed-devices.conf.**this lists all unmanaged devices, in our case creating 10-globally-managed-devices.conf** ethernet is is exceptional from being unmanaged: check this for instance **[keyfile]
unmanaged-devices=*,except:type:wifi,except:type:gsm,except:type:cdma,except:type:wwan,except:type:ethernet,except:type:vlan**

Comment: I hope you understand this one out.

Comment: 22.10: `Unit network-manager.service not found`

Answer (score 6):

As @JoshuaJohns states above, here is the answer for 20.04+:

1. As root, edit /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf to match the following. You can use the command `sudo nano /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf` to do so.

   ```
   [main]
   plugins=ifupdown,keyfile

   [ifupdown]
   managed=true

   [keyfile]
   unmanaged-devices=*,except:type:wifi,except:type:gsm,except:type:cdma,except:type:wwan,except:type:ethernet,except:type:vlan

   [device]
   wifi.scan-rand-mac-address=no
   ```

   Save and close the file. (In nano, you can do this by pressing CTRL-X, Y, then Enter.)
2. Restart the network manager service with `sudo systemctl restart network-manager`.

Comment: Possibly noteworthy, with all the exceptions, one could probably just set `unmanaged-devices=none` and be done (it seems to be working fine in my case).

Comment: 22.10: `Unit network-manager.service not found`?